# File doesn't upload windows form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-services, setup-project, openfiledialog

I create a windows service and a setup project.
I create a windows form to upload a file for my setup project.

My issue is when I click on my file to upload it, my file doesn't upload.
And the form doesn't close too.

**ProjectInstaller of my windows service**

```
public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
{
    base.Install(stateSaver);

    Form1 validationForm = new Form1(Context.Parameters["TARGETDIR"]);
    validationForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

**Windows form**

```
private static string folderToUploadFile = string.Empty;
public Form1(string folder)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    folderToUploadFile = folder;
    label1.Text = folder;
}

private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var task = new Thread(() => {

        try
        {
            OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            fileDialog.Filter = "Dat files |*.dat";
            fileDialog.Multiselect = false;

            if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                var filename = fileDialog.FileName;
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    File.Copy(filename, folderToUploadFile);
                    this.Close();
                });

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }


    });
    task.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    task.Start();
    task.Join();
}
```

Comment: Do you see any errors? Try removing the Task.Run around the File.Copy and this.Close()

Comment: @RyanThomas there is no error and if I remove the Task.Run the state of my windows form is not responding

Comment: Instead of using Task.Run - does it work if you do Task.Factory.StartNew? Also I think you may need to add a file name onto the end of the folderToUploadFile

Comment: Also be aware, manually copying files into the install directory will mean they are not removed by the uninstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me, I have made the following changes:

1. Use Task.Factory.StartNew instead of Task.Run
2. Added some logic for combining paths.

Your button click should look something like this.

```
try
{
    OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    //fileDialog.Filter = "Dat files |*.dat";
    fileDialog.Multiselect = false;

    if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var fullPath = fileDialog.FileName;
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fullPath);

        var destination = Path.Combine(folderToUploadFile, fileName);

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            File.Copy(fullPath, destination);
            this.Close();
        });

    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Please be aware manually copying files to the install directory, will mean they remain after an uninstall, so you may wish to handle this.

**EDIT:**

You don't actually need the Task.Factory.StartNew().... Task.Run should work the same.